# What are the classics/giants of Biblical Theology?

Tags: theological-frameworks

Two of the popular ways of analyzing the Bible are: Biblical Theology and Systematic Theology.

Based on [Biblical Theology vs Systematic Theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/what-is-the-difference-between-biblical-and-systematic-theology), Biblical Theology focuses more on verses; whereas Systematic Theology focuses more on topics.

Who are the giants in Biblical Theology?

What are the classics / great works in Biblical Theology?

Related question on [Systematic Theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9187/what-are-the-classics-giants-in-systematic-theology) (Split into multiple questions as requested.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the classics/giants in Systematic Theology](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9187/what-are-the-classics-giants-in-systematic-theology)

Comment: @David these are not the same question.

Comment: This is really open to opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem rude but as **Biblical Theology as a label is a recent invention and those who willfully take that label are unknown compared to the greats of Christian history, there are none**.

There are just a few people within limited circles that feel Biblical Theology is the new way to better explain theology. They include such names as **Geerhardus Vos who in some ways is the father of Biblical Theology. Graeme Goldsworthy who is possibly the modern spokesperson of the philosophy. Other names I have seen but have never read are Herman Ridderbos, Meredith and Vaughan Roberts.**

From what I can tell this view is more popular among evangelical anglicans and specifically and proactively supported by Moore College, an evangelical anglican college in Australia.

Having said this I think Moore college is pretty good, compared to most. Also there is a lot about the term that carries very good and refined theological ideas. Its only weakness (in my view) is how it tries to argue that we should not really use the word 'new' in the New Testament and that the Laws of Moses were 'gracious'.  That said the good aspects of showing the 'gradual development and progressive and harmonious revelation' of Gods word are possibly better understood by reading Jonathan Edwards [History of Redemption](http://philologos.org/__eb-bhot/), or Alfred Edersheim's 
[The Bible History, Old Testament](http://www.preteristarchive.com/Books/1776_edwards_history-redemption.html), both which show the natural progression of revelation with anointed skill. Although they predate the philosophy of Biblical Theology, to put this philosophy under the best possible terms we could say they are the unrecognized 'greats' of what Biblical theology claims as its modern and  noble aims.

Comment: Accepted since "proof of nonexistence" is useful too.