# What is the first documented usage of "Prima Scriptura"?

Tags: terminology, origin, sola-scriptura, prima-scriptura

While the concept may have existed far prior, a recent discussion has left me wondering - What is the earliest documented usage of the term "Prima Scriptura" in Christian writings. I am not interested in articulation of the concept, but instead of the first documented usage of this specific and actual phrase in reference to the doctrine (not just coincidental usage) - so please be sure to include a quote in your answer.

Comment: This site might be a good place to begin: <https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/68278/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-prima-scriptura-and-the-background-against-which>

Comment: @James Shewey Actually I did a research for this question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/73914/10672) which provided the quotes you are looking for.  But if for this question you are asking specifically to reference a "doctrine", I have yet to see any organization teaching "Prima Scriptura" as a doctrine with that specific name, in contrast with "Sola Scriptura" where there are many churches / denominations teaching it.  Can you clarify your intention?

Comment: @GreatfulDisciple - I actually think it was your answer that more or less spawned the answer. Your statement "usage came first, then the term came later" made me wonder who came up with the term to describe the doctrine.